# Не могу набрать текст в PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Не могу писать в созданом файле, есть только белый прямоугольник.
Понажимал случайным образом на клавиши и все заработало, но нужную комбинацию нашел только два раза.
версии pycharm profesional 2017 3.2 и Community Edition 2017.3.3
OC windows 7 sp1 x32
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: File -> Settings -> Plugins, отключить плагин IdeaVim (напомнило вопрос "[как выйти из Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor)")

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+Alt+V Vim эмулятор
Tools-> Vim

Answer (score 3):

При установке IDE в системе Windows- установили плагин Vim, чтобы это исправить нужно его отключить/удалить (File -> Setings -> Plugins и во вкладке installed снять галочку и выбрать uninstal) и согласиться с перезагрузкой IDE.